How to specifically download manylinux wheels for Ubuntu 22.04 with pip?
I'm setting up a secure private PyPI server to host pre-validated packages for my projects. My environment is Ubuntu 22.04 (x86_64) with Python 3.10.
Here are the details:
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Kernel: 5.15.0-91-generic
Architecture: x86_64
Python Version: 3.10
I want to download manylinux wheels specifically for my platform. Here's the script I'm using to download and upload packages:
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$#" -lt 1 ]; then
  echo "Usage: $0 <package1> <package2> ... <packagen>"
  exit 1
fi

TEMP_DIR=$(mktemp -d)

PYPI_URL="http://172.28.1.6:30001"
PYPI_USERNAME="admin"
PYPI_PASSWORD="admin"

cleanup() {
  rm -rf "$TEMP_DIR"
}
trap cleanup EXIT

for PACKAGE in "$@"; do
  echo "Processing package: $PACKAGE"
  # Download the package for the specific platform
  pip download --only-binary=:all: --platform manylinux_2_17_x86_64 --python-version 3.10 --implementation cp --abi cp310 --dest "$TEMP_DIR" "$PACKAGE"
  
  if [ "$(ls -A $TEMP_DIR)" == "" ]; then
    echo "Fallback: Downloading without platform restrictions"
    pip download "$PACKAGE" -d "$TEMP_DIR"
  fi
  
  for FILE in "$TEMP_DIR"/*; do
    echo "Uploading $FILE to $PYPI_URL"
    twine upload --repository-url "$PYPI_URL" -u "$PYPI_USERNAME" -p "$PYPI_PASSWORD" "$FILE"
  done
  
  # Clean the temporary directory for the next package
  rm -rf "$TEMP_DIR"/*
done

echo "All packages have been uploaded successfully."

Despite specifying the platform and Python version, I still run into issues where not all packages are downloaded as manylinux wheels. For example, after trying to download httpie, here's the index of my PyPI server:
Index of packages
PySocks-1.7.1-py3-none-any.whl
certifi-2024.2.2-py3-none-any.whl
charset_normalizer-3.3.2-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
defusedxml-0.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
gpxpy-1.6.2-py3-none-any.whl
httpie-3.2.2-py3-none-any.whl
idna-3.7-py3-none-any.whl
markdown_it_py-3.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
mdurl-0.1.2-py3-none-any.whl
multidict-6.0.5-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
numpy-1.26.4-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
pandas-2.2.2-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
pip-24.0-py3-none-any.whl
pygments-2.18.0-py3-none-any.whl
python_dateutil-2.9.0.post0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
pytz-2024.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
requests-2.32.3-py3-none-any.whl
requests_toolbelt-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
rich-13.7.1-py3-none-any.whl
setuptools-70.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
tzdata-2024.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
urllib3-2.2.1-py3-none-any.whl

And the errors I get from Jupyter when trying to install httpie:
jovyan@test-faguilera:~$ pip install httpie
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement httpie (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for httpie

This is what I get when trying to uninstall any library, in case it reveals any clue:
jovyan@test-faguilera:~$ pip install numpy
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /opt/conda/lib/python3.11/site-packages (1.26.4)
jovyan@test-faguilera:~$ pip intall matplotlib
ERROR: unknown command "intall" - maybe you meant "install"
jovyan@test-faguilera:~$ pip uninstall numpy
Found existing installation: numpy 1.26.4
Uninstalling numpy-1.26.4:
  Would remove:
    /opt/conda/bin/f2py
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy-1.26.4.dist-info/*
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/*
Proceed (Y/n)? y
  Successfully uninstalled numpy-1.26.4
jovyan@test-faguilera:~$ 


How can I ensure that pip downloads manylinux wheels specifically for my platform and Python version?

Are there any additional options or configurations I need to consider to make this process more reliable?

Is there a way to enforce pip to only download compatible manylinux wheels without falling back to source distributions?
Thanks in advance for your help!



"How can I ensure that pip downloads manylinux wheels…Is there a way to enforce pip to only download compatible manylinux wheels without falling back to source distributions?" Nope, no way. Simply because not all packages provide binary wheels. The very httpie doesn't: https://pypi.org/project/httpie/3.2.2/#files . Python-only packages don't generate binary wheels; only packages that contain code in C/C++/Go/Rust build binary wheels and even then not of them publish such wheels. The only way is to download, build wheels and upload the wheels.
